# Como colocar estilo em tag html que estão dentro de uma variável

Tags: ckeditor, svelte

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar neste exemplo? Uso ckeditor5 com o Svelte, usando o pacote ckeditor5-svelte, e queria aumentar a imagem do preview da postagem, mas não sei como alcançar isto.

no meu código, o preview está assim, na classe Editor.svelte:

```
<div class="preview" >{@html record.title}</div>
```

e o texto de record.title, é algo assim:

```
<figure class="image"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gih2jtUuKIoZdE54flFC12c-aT2Csjn87o5ARlXWA=s96-c" alt="user-avatar"><figcaption>aaa</figcaption></figure><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porta, dui a semper faucibus, velit mas
```

O que eu queria fazer era aplicar estilo dentro das tags dessa variável, para ela preencher a largura do container. como faço isto?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ser alcançado usando o modificador `:global`, mas tome cuidado com a  especificidade do seu CSS, pois não há como o compilador do Svelte saber como aplicar as classes de escopo na sua figura.

Para evitar esse problema de escopo, vamos pegar carona na `div` que contém a imagem e usar o seletor de descendente direto (`>`).

```html
<div class="preview">{@html record.title}</div>

<style>
.preview > :global(.image) {
  /* Seus estilos aqui */
}
</style>
```